# event.keyCode != character pointed to by current selection when typing fast

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, selection, jquery-events

Having searched high and low for a decent @mention/#tag contenteditable div solution, I'm embarking on building one.

In a keyup event handler, I am using the range selection trick to get the current cursor position from which I am able to determine the last two characters entered. I'm using it, for instance, to see if a space followed by an @ has been entered to know when to invoke autocomplete. I need to be able to reliably get the current cursor position so I can handle all the annoying cases of backspacing, using the arrow keys, clicking in the area.

The problem I am having is that in my keyup handler, the keycode I am getting in the event matches what I've typed but the selection seems to be lagging when I type fast enough.

For instance, see this http://jsfiddle.net/puMCX/

```
$( '#test' ).bind( 'keyup', function( event )
   {
   var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

   console.log( "event.which char '" + String.fromCharCode( event.which ) + "' character from range :'" + $( range.startContainer ).text().charAt( range.startOffset - 1 ) + "'" );
   });
```

Click on the TEST and type in something quickly. If you type reasonably fast you will notice that the keycode and selection do not match.

```
fiddle.jshell.net:25event.which char 'T' character from range :'i'
fiddle.jshell.net:25event.which char 'H' character from range :'s'
fiddle.jshell.net:25event.which char 'I' character from range :'s'
fiddle.jshell.net:25event.which char 'S' character from range :'s'
```

Typing slowly it works just fine.

It seems the selection is getting updated before the keyup events have a chance to fire.

So the question is, how can I accurately determine the position of the cursor in a contenteditable div (and the characters surrounding said cursor position) when someone types really fast? Or even better, is there a better way to do this in a rigorous cross browser way that will accomplish the same goal?

Most other @mention/tagging plugins I've tried suffer from the same problem. Facebook, however, does not. No matter how fast I type it works as it should, so clearly there is a better way of doing it.

I am testing using Chrome under Linux.

Comment: For what it's worth, FireFox exhibits the same issue.

Comment: Also, doing the same experiment in a textarea yields the same result.

Comment: Found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512272/caret-position-not-keeping-track